# Slick slider next and prev slides css

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have slick slider and I want to add some styles to the next and prev slides, but I don't know how.
Here is js

```
$('.works-slider').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '200px',
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    slidesToShow: 1
})
```

There are some mothods to get prev and next slides, but it is not what I want.
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

ANd here is an old issue, but I can't make the same now
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slick adds the class `slick-center` to the centered element, so if you just want to style the other elements, you could achieve this in CSS with this selector:

```
.slick-slide:not(.slick-center){
  /* your custom style */
}
```

This will have an effect on all slider-elements except the center one. Since you have `slidesToShow` set to `1` that should work for the previous and next slide.

Comment: but maybe do you know is there any way to get exactly previous and next slide?

Comment: Selecting the next element is possible with `.slick-center+.slick-slide` but unfortunately CSS has no way to select a previous sibling, you'll have to use JS for that